# How to add an icon to the data in a certain Angular material column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I can't figure out how to make an icon added to the data in the Status column, I'm using Angular material.
My page markup:

```
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
            <th class="auto-buy__table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              {{ column.header }}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              {{ column.cell(row) }}
              <button (click)="onEditSession(row)" class="auto-buy__table-button">
                <img *ngIf="column.columnDef == 'removeButton'" class="auto-buy__table-icon"
                     src="assets/img/edit-icon.svg" alt="edit"/>
              </button>
              <button (click)="onRemoveSession(row)" class="auto-buy__table-button">
                <img *ngIf="column.columnDef == 'editButton'" class="auto-buy__table-icon"
                     src="assets/img/trash-icon.svg" alt="remove"/>
              </button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
```

I want this result
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JskuS.gif)

But it turns out like this
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlxKH.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set a `height` and `width` for you `img` elements, that will fix your issue.

Or you could use the provided Angular Material Icons instead of using separate images, you can find a big icon list [here](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-material-icons-list-mat-icon-list/)

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let column of columns"
    [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef"
  >

    <th class="auto-buy__table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      {{ column.header }}
    </th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{ column.cell(row) }}
      <button (click)="onEditSession(row)" class="auto-buy__table-button">
        Edit
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon> <!-->Material Icon</-->
      </button>
      <button (click)="onRemoveSession(row)" class="auto-buy__table-button">
        Remove
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon> <!-->Material Icon</-->
      </button>
    </td>

  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no, you didn't understand me, the two buttons that I have are in their place, I added changed the picture of how I need to do and how I have

Comment: @qwfrjk You want to have the buttons edit and remove in the same column?

Comment: I want to add an icon "?" after Active Inactive